# Display data from REST API and update page - Express.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I'm using Express.JS and trying to display statistics of my work's HelpDesk system.

The HelpDesk software has it's own REST API. example:("servicedesk.co.uk:8080/sdpapi/request?INPUT_DATA=bla")

Currently, I am calling the API and returning the data I need. In my '**Index.js**' I have:

(I'm using *node-rest-client*)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var callCount = 0;
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var client = new Client();
  client.get("http://servicedesk.co.uk:8080/sdpapi/request?INPUT_DATA=bla", function (data, response) {
    // parsed response body as js object
    callCount = (data.operation.details.length);
    res.render('index', { title: 'ServiceDesk Dashboard', appSupportCallCount: callCount });
  });
});
```

---

This passes the data I want, to my 'index.hbs'.

What I want, is to somehow monitor the existing REST API, for any changes(i.e. when a new support ticket is raised in the helpdesk system). Then update the data being displayed on my 'index.hbs' - preferrably without the page actually reloading.

I've been looking into socket.io, long polling, etc. but cannot seem to find a way of accomplishing this.

If it cannot be completely real-time. Then I guess I can periodically, make the request to the API and then send the new response to my index.hbs - not sure how I'd do this though.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: if you want a live feed, I suggest socket.io. You state that you've tried it. would you provide some code? maybe we can help you solve the socket problem?

Comment: @R.Gulbrandsen Will socket.io work with the REST API I'm using? I had been following this tutorial: http://www.programwitherik.com/getting-started-with-socket-io-node-js-and-express/ Most tutorials I see, seem to concentrate on the app.js file and using 'app.get', Whereas I'm using my index.js with 'router.get'

Comment: Short answer, yes. You connect your client to the server a little bit different though. and that my friend, depends on what client lib you're using..